# Laravel - How to get the value of input in a view

Tags: php, html, jquery, laravel

I'm building a page with 2 forms like this:

index.blade.php:

```
<form action="/" method="post">
  <input type="text" list="cats" name="catipt" id="catipt" />
    <datalist id="cats">
      @foreach($categories as $category)
        <option>{{ $category->name }}</option>
      @endforeach
    </datalist>
  <button type="submit">Add</button>
</form>

@include("catForms")
```

catForms.blade.php contains a `form` aside from the first one, with a send button to send the form input via email. The second form in which there are many `div` that each has `input` for the user to fill in. The first form allows user to add items to the dropdown list, so it's a post method. Based on the input in the first `form`, a corresponding `div` in second `form` will show, others will hide, using Jquery. Now, I want to send the data from the user via email, but how do I get the value of the input in the first `form` in the email view so that I can filter out the irrelevant `div`? Otherwise, I'll have to list out all `div` even they are empty.

The problem is that, there are two forms, so there are two `Request $request`, I can't get the `input` value from the first `form` in email view. I tried this in email view, but this doesn't work:

```
@php
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\Input;
@endphp

Cat: {{ Input::get('catipt') }}
```

Comment: HTML form can be submitted only one per page... when do you expect to fetch that input?? When you click submit or what???

Comment: @lewis4u But I have two forms. And each has its own submit button, and will go to different controller. It was working fine.

Comment: I decided to create an additional hidden input in the second `form`, and if first `input` is changed, the hidden one will have the same effect, then I can use `Request $request` to get the first `input` value.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="/" method="post">
  <input type="text" list="cats" name="catipt" id="catipt" />
    <datalist id="cats" name="cat-name">
      @foreach($categories as $category)
        <option value="{{ $category->name }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
      @endforeach
    </datalist>
  <button type="submit">Add</button>
</form>
```